# Fading in text from right to left in SVG(1.1)

Tags: css, animation, svg, path, fadein

I am new in SVG and trying to fading In text from right to left using **SVG(1.1)**.
I created the simple animation path from codepen.io and now I want to appear text each character one after another.
e.g we have text "I am animation" so once animation start first of all **n** letter popup then [**o i t a m i a**] each character one by one same like the animation fade Out at the end of the SVG path.
I tried with opacity and transition properties but not working as expected.

```js
document.getElementById("pathX").setAttribute("d",document.getElementById("svgPath").getAttribute("d"));
var tl = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1});


tl.to("#Text",20,{attr:{
startOffset:'100%'

}
}

);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);

body{ background-color: #FFF;}
svg{
  overflow:visible;
  left:5%;  top:25%;  position:absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
 
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Animation</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.1/TimelineMax.min.js"></script>
</head>

<svg version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/" x="0px" y="0px" width="363.652px" height="363.954px" 
  viewBox="-70 30 363.652 363.954" enable-background="new 0 0 363.652 363.954"
     xml:space="preserve" >
   
 <defs><path  id="pathX"/></defs>
    <path  id="svgPath" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-miterlimit="10"   
  d="M 150 200 L 500 200 A 50 50 0 1 1 500 350"
 />
 
 
    <text font-size="40px" style="fill-opacity:5" >
         <textPath id="Text" fill='blue' font-family=arial xlink:href="#pathX" startOffset="0">
     I am animation
   </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: make each letter a tspan and animate the opacity of each tspan individually.

Comment: @RobertLongson can you please provide any sample code

Comment: Here's an alternative idea, you try it and update the question if you get stuck.